# Is it possible to get CPU and Memory in GUI for PID in UBUNTU

Tags: performance, user-interface, ubuntu, pid

Is it possible to get GUI of memory and CPU usage for particular   Process ID(jar) in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Terminal and type 'top' => Enter (You can view the CPU and Memory consumption for all PID's)

2) There is an inbuilt GUI application (Ubuntu 18.04LTS) called 'System Monitor' which does the same

Comment: I tried top command.  But i want User interface for viewing my application(jar) cpu and memory consumption

Comment: 2. Have you tried Genome - 'System Monitor' application(inbuilt) ?

Comment: i tried that also i am getting below error  gnome-system-monitor
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-system-monitor:15123): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: I am using JConsole here.